# Best lossy format for music?

Tags: compression, mp3

Which one of the lossy file formats like Ogg, AAC, Mp3, Wma has the best quality/size ratio?
I've seen that AACs are smaller than MP3 at the same bitrates. Do they sound worse than MP3?

Comment: From the graph referred to by @D_adams, I gather that they converge over 128kb/s.  Your question needs to specify "how much" and "what use".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may find a lot of subjective answers here, and some of the quality seems to be dependent on what you play the files on - for example AAC and low quality mp3s will be fine on your iPod through headphones, but pop them on a decent system with good speakers and they will sound crap ([Skeptics question here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/3219/619))

Each of the lossy formats has its own way of deciding what to lose (the wonderfully named [psychoacoustics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychoacoustics)) and you may prefer one over another.

I don't like the way AAC, Mp3 or WMA compression sounds on low or medium bitrates, but on high I can't tell the difference between them. Ogg I actually like slightly less at low bitrates than the others, but morally I like it :-)

So I use mp3 or ogg in all my audio players, at high bitrate/quality settings (or flac in the devices that support it)

Answer (score 3):

A good place to look for this type of info is [Hydrogenaudio](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Main_Page). But... because this is so subjective (quality) it ultimately comes down to doing some listening tests yourself.

As a purely pragmatic thing, I'd use .mp3 for lossy compression as it's established itself as the gold standard for better or worse.

Answer (score 1):

I personally think that WMA or Ogg sound better at lower bitrates than MP3.  At higher bitrates I don't notice as much of a difference.

For my MP3 player I tend to encode everything at the smallest file size I can without constantly hearing the compression artifacts.

I currently am using Ogg at [compression level 0](http://vorbis.com/faq/#quality) which is roughly equivilant to 64 Kbps.  The only thing I don't like about the format is that Windows Media Player does not like it, so I must add my music to my MP3 player manually instead of being able to sync using WMP.